# Pandas: Speeding up many string searches

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series where each element is an empty list:

```
matches = pd.Series([[]]*4)
```

and another series of strings:

```
strs = pd.Series(["word3, xx word1 word1", "yy", "word2. o", "awldkj"])
```

I want to populate `cats` with case insensitive keyword matches from a set of keywords:

```
terms = ["word1", "Word2", "worD3"]
```

Currently, I iterate through each search term individually

```
    for tcat in tcats:
        tcat_re = rf'\b{tcat}\b'
        has_cat = strs.str.contains(tcat_re, case=False)
        print(has_cat.sum(), "matches for", tcat)
        w_cats = has_cat.map({True: [tcat], False: []})
        cats = cats.combine(w_cats, lambda li, li2: li + li2)
```

which yields the correct solution:

```
1 matches for word1
1 matches for Word2
1 matches for worD3

In [507]: matches
Out[509]: 
0    [word1, worD3]
1                []
2           [Word2]
3                []
```

Two aspects to notice:

- The order of matching terms in `matches` does not matter
- `word1` appears twice in `strs.iloc[0]` but only yields 1 match. It's fine if 2 matches are generated since the list can be mapped to a set and then back to list

But much too slowly, since my real word `terms` list and `strs` series is much much larger. Any way to speed it up?

Comment: can you try `strs.str.findall('(?i){}'.format('|'.join([rf'\b{i}\b' for i in terms]))).map(set)`  ?

Comment: @anky Seems to work? Is this solution equivalent, but a bit cleaner? `strs.str.findall('|'.join([rf'\b{i}\b' for i in terms]), flags=re.IGNORECASE).map(set)`

Comment: what you have in your comment is same as my comment except `(?i)` which is ignorecase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
strs.str.findall('(?i){}'.format('|'.join([rf'\b{i}\b' for i in terms]))).map(set)

0    {word1, word3}
1                {}
2           {word2}
3                {}
```

Or for preserving order:

```
(strs.str.findall('(?i){}'.format('|'.join([rf'\b{i}\b' for i in terms])))
                               .map(lambda x: [*dict.fromkeys(x).keys()]))

0    [word3, word1]
1                []
2           [word2]
3                []
```

Comment: You'll also want to use `rf'\b{re.escape(}i)\b'` allowing for arbitrary terms